# How do I make AlpineJS work with Dynamic x-data from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, magento, magento2, alpine.js

So I have a table like so in a PHTML File
(pseudo code):

```php
foreach ($_children as $child) {
echo '<table  x-data="{ showProduct-'. $child->getId() . ': false }">'

echo ' 
<tr>
 <td>
   <button x-on:click="showProduct-'. $child->getId() . ' = !showProduct-'. $child->getId() . '">
     Dropdown
   </button>
 </td>  
</tr>
'

echo '
<tr class="product-'. $child->getId() . '">
  <td class="product-card" colspan="8" x-show="showProduct-'. $child->getId() . '">
    Some Dynamic card content for every ID with PHP
  </td>
</tr>
    
</table>
'
}
```

I am trying to load a piece of dynamic code(card) dependent on ID from the php side for each `product-ID` in my template file, which I would like to only display per ID based on if the corresponding button for that ID was clicked. So if button with `x-data = showProduct-11` gets clicked only that particular card gets displayed.

However it is not working for some reason.

How can I make something like this work?

Answer (score 0):

In JS the hyphen `-` is the [subtraction operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Subtraction), so `showProduct-11` actually means: `showProduct - 11`. Replace it with e.g. underscore (`showProduct_'. $child->getId() . '`), or remove it to fix this issue.